# RHEL packetmanager

Tags: redhat

I am working for some years with debian on engineering/administration level and using apt as packetmanager.

Now I have to work with a RHEL and I need some quick overview of how to handle packetmanagement there. I know the rpm-tool but not very well.

I am looking especially for this:
- how can I link my local PM to a paket-repository in the internet or on CD
- is rpm just for single files (like dpkg) or also for managin (like apt-get: searching etc)

so apt on debian is very cool. is there something comparable in RHEL too??

cheers, chris

Answer (score 0):

> is rpm just for single files (like dpkg) or also for managin (like apt-get: searching etc)

Not quite. Rpm is for Redhat what dpkg is for Debian. The Redhat equivalent of apt-tools/aptitute is *yum*.

> I am looking especially for this: - how can I link my local PM to a paket-repository in the internet or on CD

Redhat puts repositories in files, rather then a single sources.list file. You find those repo-definitions in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`. So see what repositories are available, you use the command `yum repolist`. For instance, this Scientific Linux system of mine it gives the following output:

```
# yum repolist
repo id           repo name                                               status
epel              Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64          6.416
sl                Scientific Linux 6.1 - x86_64                           6.251
sl-security       Scientific Linux 6.1 - x86_64 - security updates          336
repolist: 13.003
```

If you want to add a repository, you either try getting a predefined file (hint: almost any 3rd party repository gives you an rpm which does everything automatically) or write your own repository defintion. Put it in a file called reponame.repo in /etc/yum.repos.d/. This is an example from the EPEL project:

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
```

`$basearch` resolves to `uname -m`, so to x86_64 or i686. If you set everything up correctly (mandatory settings are name, baseurl and enabled=1), run `yum update` and check with `yum repolist` if your repository was correctly included.

Usually you'll only use yum; rpm alone is rarely used. If you're used to aptitude, yum won't be much of a challenge for you for the commands like update/upgrade/clean/erase are pretty much the same.

The yum documentation can be found on Fedora's webpage: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Software_Management_Guide/index.html

Good luck!
Alex.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu "dkpg" -> RHEL -> "rpm"
Ubuntu "apt-get install ****" RHEL -> "yum install ****"

There are various unofficial available for RHEL and if you are subscribed to RHN then you get the packages directly from Red Hat Network.

Configuration files in /etc/yum.repos.d/